# Deploying to gcloud app engine throws NPM errors

Tags: google-app-engine, npm, gcloud

I wrote an application (NodeJS 12, Express) which installs and works locally, and would like to deploy it on gcloud's app engine.

My app.yaml:

```
service: staging runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

When deploying to google cloud's app engine, I'm getting this error:

```
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: npm ERR! object.assign not accessible from es-abstract
```

Other projects deploy fine.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the `runtime` in the `app.yaml` to `nodejs14` made the issue disappear. I know this might not be a perfect solution for everyone, but if your code is fine with a different node version it might help.